# Where am I wrong in my solution?

Tags: probability

A probability question reads,

"A box contains $4$ balls. The color of each of the balls is one of the three: White, Black, or Red. However, you don't know how many balls of each color are there. It might even be the case that all the balls are of the same color. You then draw two balls randomly from the box. What is the probability that both the drawn balls are red?"

My solution:- Total combinations of $4$ balls of $3$ colors = $^6C_2 = 15$ (as it is combination with repetetions). ($^6C_2 = \frac{(6!)}{(4!)(2!)}$)

The probability that two red balls are drawn $= (\frac{1}{15})(1)+(\frac{2}{15})(\frac{3}{6})+(\frac{3}{15})(\frac{1}{6})=\frac16$

Reason:- There is $1$ combination where all $4$ balls are red so the probability that we draw $2$ red balls, in that case, is $1$. There are two cases where there are exactly $3$ red balls and then in that case the probability of drawing two red balls is $\frac36$. And similarly, the case when there are exactly $2$ red balls.

But the correct answer is $\frac19$. Where am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the assumptions are not clear.  If you assume that each ball is equally likely to be of any of the colors, independent of all the other balls, then each ball is red with probability $\frac 13$ so the answer is $\left( \frac 13 \right)^2=\frac 19$.  That seems to be the assumption they had in mind.

Comment: Note:  you are assuming that each combination is equally probable which seems like a stretch.  In any case, since the problem is silent regarding the assumptions, it is necessary to explicitly state whatever assumption you are making.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to think about it:

$$P(\text{Both Red}) = P(\text{Both Red} \cap \text{0 red initially}) + P(\text{Both Red} \cap \text{1 red initially}) + P(\text{Both Red} \cap \text{3 red initially}) + P(\text{Both Red} \cap \text{4 red initially}) $$

Now apply the fact that, $P(A \cap B) = P(A | B ) P(B)$.